# Using a custom template in a theme

Tags: theming

I have created the custom template page-org.tpl.page in the Zen theme, and I want to include this custom template file in the menu calling; when the user clicks on the Org link it should use the template file page-org.tpl.page.
How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome on _Drupal Answers_. To which Drupal version are you interested? Different Drupal versions use different template names; without to know to which Drupal version are you interested, it is difficult to give the correct answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Page template suggestions are not working](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1501/page-template-suggestions-are-not-working).

Answer (score 1):

Output your $vars in the theme so you can see your candidate templates.

EDIT: I thought you were looking for a content type solution when I first read this :)

**Here's a gotcha:** 
you have to have master templates before you can have ones within it. For example content-field-field_my_content.tpl.php will not work until content-field.tpl.php is in place in the theme.

You may need to place some PHP in your template.php within preprocess_page()

`if(!arg(2)) $variables['template_files'][] = 'page-node_'.$variables['node']->type;`

(The arg2 check helps make sure this doesn't happen on edit pages.)

Lastly, you can also accomplish this with [Context Layout.](http://drupal.org/project/context)

Answer (score 0):

The page template must be named: page-node-XX.tpl.php.

Replace XX by the node id of the page.

Answer (score 0):

As reported in the source code of [template_preprocess_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/6):

```
// Build a list of suggested template files in order of specificity. One
// suggestion is made for every element of the current path, though
// numeric elements are not carried to subsequent suggestions. For example,
// http://www.example.com/node/1/edit would result in the following
// suggestions:
//
// page-node-edit.tpl.php
// page-node-1.tpl.php
// page-node.tpl.php
// page.tpl.php
```

Similar comment is contained in the code source of [theme_get_suggestions()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_get_suggestions/7), which is the function called from `template_preprocess_page()` in Drupal 7:

```
//One suggestion is made for every element of the current path,
// though numeric elements are not carried to subsequent suggestions. For
// example, for $base='page', http://www.example.com/node/1/edit would result
// in the following suggestions and body classes:
//
// page__node              page-node
// page__node__%           page-node-%
// page__node__1           page-node-1
// page__node__edit        page-node-edit
```

Supposing that the link takes to http://example.com/links/org, then the template file for that page should be page-links-org.tpl.php or page-org.tpl.php for Drupal 6, and page--links--org.tpl.php or page--org.tpl.php for Drupal 7.