# Templating a form

Tags: 7, theming

I'd like to change the template of a form that I created via a module but I do not know what I'm doing exactly as I have snippets of "information." For information, this form is in 'node /add/page' or 'node/add/article'.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Page template suggestions are not working](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1501/page-template-suggestions-are-not-working).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your help. I managed to find what I wanted.

I used this:

```
$ form ['takealook'] = array (
     '# type' => 'fieldset',
     '# title' => t ('Take a look settings'),
     '# description' => t ('Determines if users Cdn The Access limited to a page. '),
     '# collapsible' => TRUE,
     '# collapsed' => TRUE,
     '# group' => 'additional_settings'
     '# access' => user_access ('takealook_administer')
     '# Attached' => array (
       'js' => array (drupal_get_path ('module', 'takealook') '. / takealook.js')
     )
     '# attributes' => array ('class' => array ('takealook-settings-form')),
   );
```

This code is to create groups with tabs or add to existing group "additional_settings"

Answer (score 3):

Try using the [Theme Developer module](https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) to find which function or template file is outputting the form you're interested in theming. Theme Developer will also tell you what "suggestions" you can use to override the output. Check out the [Theme Developer screencast](http://drupal.org/node/209561) for an introduction on how to use the module.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I managed to find what I wanted.

I used this:
[code]
   $ form ['takealook'] = array (
     '# type' => 'fieldset',
     '# title' => t ('Take a look settings'),
     '# description' => t ('Determines if users Cdn The Access limited to a page. ")
     '# group' => 'additional_settings'
     '# access' => user_access ('takealook_administer')
     '# Attached' => array (
       'js' => array (drupal_get_path ('module', 'takealook') '. / takealook.js')
     )
     '# attributes' => array ('class' => array ('takealook-settings-form')),
   );