# How can I create a new page template for the user registration page?

Tags: forms, users

I am a beginner in Drupal. I need to create a new page template for the registration page. Because in my website almost all pages have different layout.

Currently all pages are rendering through `page.tpl.php`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

There are so many ways to theming your registration page.
You can create `user-register.tpl.php`

To know about how to create `user-register.tpl.php` refer below links.

https://www.drupal.org/node/1211520

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user-profile.tpl.php/7

https://www.drupal.org/node/1195754

If you want to know how to create tpl files.

[Page template suggestions are not working](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1501/page-template-suggestions-are-not-working)